# Why do Fama French's "Common risk factors in the returns on stocks and bonds" use data starting in 1963? Availability or convenience for results?

Tags: equities, fixed-income, interest-rates, returns, fama-french

What is the reason Fama French's "Common risk factors in the returns on stocks and bonds" use data starting in 1963? Was it availability or convenience for results?

Answer (score 1):

In their other paper from that year "The cross-section of expected stock returns" they mention that the COMPUSTAT data for earlier years have a serious selection bias; the pre-1962 data are tilted toward big historically successful firms."